# Python numpy Indexing multidimensional array

Tags: python, numpy

For each row of `y` I would like to get element whose indexes are specified in `m`.

```
>>> y = np.arange(15).reshape(3,5)
[[ 0  1  2  3  4]
 [ 5  6  7  8  9]
 [10 11 12 13 14]]

>>> m = np.array([[0, 1], [1, 2], [2, 3]])
```

**Expected output:**

```
[[0, 1]
 [6, 7]
 [12, 13]]
```

**Solution with `for` cycle**

```
>>> np.stack([y[i, cols] for i, cols in enumerate(m)])
```

Is there a way how to do it without a `for` cycle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using values from one array as index from another is called 'fancy indexing', however that indexing operation will be repeated for all rows:

```
y = numpy.arange(15).reshape(3,5)
y[:, [0, 2, 3]]
# array([[ 0,  2,  3],
#        [ 5,  7,  8],
#        [10, 12, 13]])
```

If you want to individually "use one index value per row", you need to give that row-to-index relation as another index:

```
y[[0, 1, 2], [0, 2, 3]]
# array([ 0,  7, 13])
```

Since your index array `m` is 2D, you need to tell NumPy which of these two dimension in `m` corresponds to your row index. You do this by adding another empty axis to the ascending index, (keyword: broadcasting), and you get

```
y = numpy.arange(15).reshape(3,5)
m = numpy.array([[0, 1], [1, 2], [2, 3]])

y[numpy.arange(len(m))[:, None], m]
# array([[ 0,  1],
#        [ 6,  7],
#        [12, 13]])
```

Answer (score 1):

One line, although not much nicer than your own proposal using the for loop:

```
y[..., m][np.identity(3, dtype=bool)]
```

Though it will give you some insights in numpy indexing.